# How to assign a variable based on a group by variable?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the following data frame

```
filenumber<-c('510-1','510-1','510-2','510-3','510-3')
Year<-c('2017','2018','2018','2018','2019')
outcome<-c('Accepted',"Completed","Accepted","Accepted","Completed")

df<-data.frame(filenumber,Year,outcome)
```

I want to make sure that if a `filenumber` was `Accepted` in a given `Year` I name all files associated with that `Year` as e.g "cohort" followed by the year it was accepted

```
df%>%group_by(filenumber)%>%mutate(cohort=case_when(Year=='2017' & outcome=='Accepted'~'cohort-2017',
                                                    Year=='2018' & outcome=='Accepted'~'cohort-2018'))

 filenumber Year  outcome   cohort     
 510-1      2017  Accepted  cohort-2017
 510-1      2018  Completed NA         
 510-2      2018  Accepted  cohort-2018
 510-3      2018  Accepted  cohort-2018
 510-3      2019  Completed NA
```

However, I want to make sure that the cohort applies to the filenumber that has `Accepted` as an outcome so I can something like this

```
 filenumber Year  outcome   cohort     
 510-1      2017  Accepted  cohort-2017
 510-1      2018  Completed cohort-2017         
 510-2      2018  Accepted  cohort-2018
 510-3      2018  Accepted  cohort-2018
 510-3      2019  Completed cohort-2018
```

How I do I do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `fill` from `tidyr` at the end

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df%>%
  group_by(filenumber)%>%mutate(cohort=case_when(Year=='2017' & 
    outcome=='Accepted'~'cohort-2017',
               Year=='2018' & outcome=='Accepted'~'cohort-2018')) %>% 
  fill(cohort)
# A tibble: 5 x 4
# Groups:   filenumber [3]
#  filenumber Year  outcome   cohort     
#  <fct>      <fct> <fct>     <chr>      
#1 510-1      2017  Accepted  cohort-2017
#2 510-1      2018  Completed cohort-2017
#3 510-2      2018  Accepted  cohort-2018
#4 510-3      2018  Accepted  cohort-2018
#5 510-3      2019  Completed cohort-2018
```

---

It can be simplified as well.  After grouping by 'filenumber', `match` the 'Accepted' string on the 'outcome' to get the numeric index, based on that index, subset the 'Year' and `paste` the 'cohort-' string to create the 'cohort' column

```
library(stringr)
df %>% 
    group_by(filenumber) %>% 
    mutate(cohort = str_c('cohort-', Year[match('Accepted', outcome)]))
```